# Unable to display this Web Part

Tags: web-part

Unable to display this Web Part.

> To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator."

Error comes up when I click on a webpart how can we fix

Comment: Which webpart? Have you edited the page in SharePoint Designer? Are you able to open the page?

Comment: we have created a sharepoint template for our project workspaces. We have a several list that are web parts, all give back same message, after refreshing several times the part dispays

Comment: Check the log files. It seems issue with your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the site in SharePoint Designer?
Remove all the webparts on the page, and start adding one by one to isolate which one might be causing it. I'm thinking its a reference on the page or maybe the masterpage was edited and not published/checked in by a different user. Careful, that you dont have the page open in multiple tabs/browsers.